# Why would Cotton Hill buy shin jelly?

Tags: character, king-of-the-hill

On *The Final Shinshult* episode of King of the Hill Col. Hill says that he was out buying shin jelly (without a license) when he was pulled over.

If his shins were blown off by the Tojos who were spitting on the US flag when he rushed them after saving Brooklyn and Stinky and his feet were sewn to his knees then wouldn't shin jelly be the one thing he'd **never** need to buy?

Similarly, in a flashback to the VA hospital he says "I come in here once a year to get my shins drained". Is this a mistake by the writers? He only has thighs, knees and feet, right? He went from 6'4" to 5'0" (according to the character profile on Wikia.com) so every single bit of his shins must've been lost.

Comment: It sounds like that's the gag, you're left asking 'why would a man with no shins need shin jelly'?

Comment: @user7812 Maybe, but I don't know. That wouldn't explain why he comes in to the VA once per year to get his shins drained. It seems like it's a given that shins are a recurring joke with him and maybe the writers just got it backwards when they were trying to think of something funny and looked at the word "shins" on the list of jokes for this character.